# Estimating a phase for a frequency band

Tags: fft, phase, estimation

I'm looking for a way (preferably already implemented in eg. python) of estimating a phase for a specified freq band.

When I'm performing FFT on the signal, I can determine components frequencies as well as phases of interesting components. If I understand this well, a single complex number in the FFT result table is, in fact, a representation of some (small and determined by the sampling rate and length of signal) freq band. But what if I want specific a frequency band on my own? Eg. I want to estimate a phase (single number) for a frequency band of 9-11 Hz. I guess even it's possible, some information will be lost. But can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Phase needs a reference.  What time (or other reference point) do you consider to be zero phase?  Without that, phase of a signal is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a single complex number in the FFT result table is, in fact, a representation of some (small and determined by the sampling rate and length of signal) freq band

Not really. The DFT is first and foremost a mathematical procedure that simply allows representing a time domain sequence as a sum of complex exponentials. The physical interpretation of that operation depends a lot on the circumstances but in general it's NOT true that FFT coefficient at some frequency $\omega$ represents accurately what's happening physically at frequency $\omega$. They are related but the exact nature of the relationship depends a lot on the details.

The notable exception here are time sequences that are periodic with the FFT length, but periodicity implies infinite length which doesn't exist in the real world.

> want to estimate a phase (single number) for a frequency band of 9-11 Hz.

That would require you to first define what a single number phase for a frequency band is. Typically the phase is different at each frequency, so typically a single number doesn't
work well.